# Internationalization Upgrade to 7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, upgrading

I have upgraded a site which had Internationalization installed.

After the upgradation, I tried to access www.mysite.com/fr and it led me "page not found" page.

I have enabled all the modules which comes with internationalization.

So is it with the configuration that the issue can be fixed or the drupal upgrade has not done properly.

Please let me know the correct steps to upgrade Internationalization to drupal 7.

Tks
Vil

Comment: Did you enable the languages at .../admin/config/regional/language ?

Comment: Oh wait, I didnt enabled the url and Session setting under "Detection and Selection". Enabled those and it started working. Tks for your help too.